# Shell command to get config values

Tags: shell, command-line, command, sh

I am using the sh 3.2 in Mac Os X. I have a file test.conf

```
config1="Configuration 1"
config2="a lot of text"
config3=...
```

So I only need to get the `config1=` and `config2=` parameter. How can I set a variable, that I can do this:

```
> echo $variable
Configuration 1
```

So simple, but I am not doing it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the sommand you are looking for is `source`

```
source test.conf
echo $config1        #echoes Configuration 1
```

if you need to have config1 in variable, add

```
varible=$config1
```

Comment: Still doesn't work if the variables have spaces in them.  And the question asked for selectively picking some of the variables in test.conf.

Answer (score 1):

At a rough guess...

```
export `grep 'config1=' /your/config/file`
export `grep 'config2=' /your/config/file`
```

But remember if you put this in a shell script file, then you'll need to eval the file rather than execute it to set the variables in the current shell instance.

Comment: Work to, but will need one by variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
variable=`sed -n 's/^config1=//p'`
```

Or if you are attempting to evaluate certain parts of your file, try something like

```
eval `grep ^config1= test.conf`
```

to have `config1=Configuration 1` evaluated by the current shell.  (With the example you provided, this will cause a syntax error, because the value cannot contain unquoted whitespace.)

I generally recommend beginners to stay away from backticks, but this is a situation where they are a good answer.